# MySQL Delete in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

The problem is simple, delete duplicate rows in a `table`

So if the table is:

```
| id | name |
| 1  | aaaaa    |
| 2  | bbbbb    |
| 3  | aaaaa    |
```

the output result will is:

```
| id | name |
| 1  | aaaaa    |
| 2  | bbbbb    |
```

This is the query I am using:

```
delete t1 
  from Table t1
     , Table t2 
 where t1.name = t2.name 
   and t1.Id > t2.Id
```

the above query works fine.

However, I modify the query a little:

```
delete 
  from Table 
 where Id in (select t1.Id from Table t1, Table t2 where t1.name = t2.name and t1.Id > t2.Id)
```

when executing it, the error message is "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause"

My question is why this subquery can not be executed correctly? What is the story behind the scene

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Because selecting the table puts a read lock on the records, which then you are trying to alter.